# Why a guard exists in this implementation of a lock?

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, locking

Here in [this video](https://youtu.be/DaOLlnOV0s0?t=1560) at `26:00`, there is an implementation of a lock that tries to avoids busy waiting as much as possible by using a wait queue, the code looks like this (pseudo code):

```
int guard = 0;
int value = FREE;

Acquire()
{
    while (test_and_set(guard));

    if (value == BUSY) {
        release_guard_and_wait();
    } else {
        value = BUSY;
        guard = 0;
    }
}

Release()
{
    while (test_and_set(guard));

    if (!wait_queue.empty())
        wake_one();
    else
        value = FREE;
        
    guard = 0;
}
```

`test_and_set` is an atomic operation that returns the old value of `guard` and sets it to `1`.

---

`release_guard_and_wait` has to be atomic as well to avoid potential problems:

If the thread waits then releases the guard when it wakes up, no thread will be able to acquire it.

If the thread releases the guard then waits, this scenario might happen:

- thread 1 (in Acquire) -> `guard = 0;`
- thread 2 (in Release) -> `test_and_set(guard);`
- thread 2 (in Release) -> `wake_one();`
- thread 1 (in Acquire) -> `wait();`
- thread 2 (in Release) -> `guard = 0;`

---

`wake_one` wakes one thread (takes it from the wait queue and puts it in the ready queue).

---

My question is, why using `guard`? isn't this redundant?

The code without `guard` may look like this:

```
int value = 0;

Acquire()
{
    while (test_and_set(value))
        wait();
}

Release()
{
    value = 0;
    wake_one();
}
```

Will these two implementations behave differently under some conditions? Is there any advantage in using the guard?

Comment: What does the wake_one(); method do?

Comment: @maio290 My bad, it wakes one thread. Takes it from the wait queue and puts it in the ready queue. I've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two big problems with your code.

First, your code has a race condition. Consider:

1. Thread 1 holds the lock, it calls `Release`.
2. Thread 2 wants the lock, it calls `Acquire`.
3. Thread 1 sets `value` to zero.
4. Thread 2 passes the `test_and_set`.
5. Thread 1 calls `wake_one`, it doesn't do anything.
6. Thread 2 calls `wait`, it is waiting for a wakeup that already happened.

Oops, deadlock. This is why you need an atomic `release_guard_and_wait` function.

Second problem:

If two threads call `Acquire` at the same time, your code will only cause one of them to wait. The other one will do horrible things, for example it will:

1. Keep a core busy, preventing other cores from reaching their peak speeds on many CPUs with adaptive clock speeds.
2. Waste power.
3. Starve another thread running in the same core on CPUs with hyperthreading and similar technologies.
4. When the spinning thread finally does pass the `test_and_set` loop, it will take a massive mispredicted branch penalty. So if several threads are waiting, each one will stall just as it gets the lock. Yuck.
5. On some CPUs, a `test_and_set` loop will cause inter-core traffic even if the comparison fails. So you may saturate inter-core buses, slowing other innocent threads (and the one holding the lock) to a crawl.

And so on.

I hate to see the test and set loop in the original code (that's only appropriate in toy code, even for very short times) but at least it won't spin for the whole time another thread holds the lock as yours will.

Comment: Thanks. 
In the second problem, I think you're assuming that my code doesn't use a wait queue and will just keep spinning until the value is set to 0, right?

Comment: @StackExchange123 For as long as one thread holds the lock and another thread is also waiting for the lock. Your code only allows one thread on the "queue". (Unless you assume the `wait` function basically replicates all the code in the other implementation.

Answer (score 1):

"there is an implementation of a lock that avoids busy waiting by using a wait channel" -- I could still see a busy waiting, in the form of this `while (test_and_set(guard));)`. But the essence of the code is making that busy wait for a short period. All your code does is this:

1. Declare a lock-queue where a process can register itself for a lock.
2. Add the process to that lock-queue, which is interested in acquiring the lock.
3. Release one process from the lock-queue, when an already holding process releases the lock.

- **Acquire()**

`while (test_and_set(guard));` -- Get the gaurd for editing the lock-queue.

`if (value == BUSY) {release_guard_and_wait();}` -- If the lock is already acquired, add yourself to the lock-queue, and release the guard on lock-queue so that other processes may add themselves to the lock-queue. And wait till you are given a call to wake up.

`else { value = BUSY; guard = 0;}` -- If no process acquired the lock, then acquire by yourself and release the guard on the lock-queue.

- **Release()**

`while (test_and_set(guard));` -- Get the gaurd for editing the lock-queue.

`if (!wait_queue.empty()) wake_one();` -- If the lock queue is not empty then wake one process.

`else value = FREE;` -- If no process is waiting for the lock in the lock-queue, just release the lock.

`guard = 0;` -- Of course at the end, release the guard on the lock-queue, so other processes can edit the queue.

Now coming to your modified code, you can immediately find that two processes running `acquire()` and `release()` may edit the queue at the same instant. Moreover, multiple processes trying to acquire the lock at the same time, may also corrupt the lock-queue and leave it in a broken state.

Comment: Indeed, it's just trying to avoid busy waiting as much as possible but of course that doesn't get rid of it completely. I'm gonna edit the question. Thanks.